# "Configure Travis CI" tab doesn't appear on Coverity Scan's "Submit Build" webpage

Tags: github, travis-ci, coverity

I'm having problems configuring Travis CI to submit my public project to Coverity Scan. I'm following the [instructions from Coverity](https://scan.coverity.com/travis_ci) but when I reach step 7, there is no `Configure Travis CI` tab:

[image: Coverity Scan "Submit Build" webpage]

As a consequence, I can't appropriately modify my `.travis.yml` file. Apparently, the project isn't "properly registered via GitHub" (whatever that means).

The relevant GitHub repository is owned by an organization of which I'm a member and I have administrative privileges on the repository.

I did log into Coverity Scan using my GitHub account.

The repository URL that Coverity Scan has is https://github.com/Unidata/LDM.git.

Any ideas on how to get the "Configure Travis CI" tab to appear?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the project a second time to Coverity Scan and choosing the "Select from GitHub" button instead of a manual entry has caused the "Configure Travis CI" tab to appear.

It's possible that the GitHub repository was added to Coverity Scan when it was owned by my personal GitHub account and that a subsequent transfer of ownership to my organization was the cause of the problem. I note that the name of the problematic Coverity Scan project isn't prefixed with my organization's name like that of the successful project.